# How can i send bits using a wien bridge oscilator?

Tags: digital-logic, rf, oscillator, modulation, signal-processing

I have a string of bits that my shift register will be outputting one after another, I want to use a wien bridge to send them into air.

If a bit is a "1", I want the wien bridge to send a wave, and no wave if bit is "0". But I noticed that the wien bridge has no input, how do i get what i want. i also don't wanna keep the oscillator powered all the time, because then, it will oscillate all the time.

[image]

Comment: You're.... either very confused or you're not explaining your question very well. What do you mean by if it's a 1, send a wave?

Comment: i mean, output a signal

Comment: Output a 1 as well? Or make a square wave? Or a sine wave? Or a single square pulse? Still very vague, and I'm not sure why you're wanting to use a wein bridge.

Comment: i thought a wien bridge produces a sine wave

Comment: It only outputs a sine wave if you have an amplitude stabilization mechanism. Your circuit doesn't have one so you'll end up at best with some sort of square wave.

Comment: If you make a wein bridge with a sinewave output you could just have an NMOS switch on the ground rail to the op-amp so that it turns on when you have a 1.

Comment: i really don't care about the integrity of the signal, i just want to have a field at the receiver. But right now, how should i send the field when my register is outputting a 3 voltage on a line, i don't see any input on wien bridge

Comment: If you've built a wein bridge oscillator, then as I said, turn it on and off by connecting the amplifier's ground connection to the drain of a mosfet. Attach the source to ground, and connect your 3V signal to the gate.

Comment: now i understand it, so the op amp is essentially not working when we have 0 because its ground is not connected. It even addresses my other problem of not wanting to live the op amp working all the time. One last concern, according to your implementation, I can leave the +Vs of the op amp connected to a battery all day and not have it drain the battery? assuming I have not sent any bits, is that correct

Comment: Yup, exactly. As long as there's no path to ground except through the NMOS and you've shut the NMOS off, then it's like an open switch. Without a closed circuit, no electrons flow and no energy is wasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm summarizing comments into an answer as they seemed to answer your question.

So long as your wein bridge oscillator oscillates properly and produces the signal that you want, you can go ahead and add a mosfet to the oscillator circuit to turn it on and off. It would go between the ground connections shown on your schematic and the actual ground wire. Then the gate of the nmos would be driven by your input signal.

When a 1 is sent to the nmos, your wein bridge oscillator will turn on and start sending a signal. When there's a 0 at the gate, the entire op-amp and related components will no longer have a path to ground and will therefore not consume any power.